# If I don't change the value of date time picker, textbox will show text

Tags: vb.net, textbox, datetimepicker

Please correct me and help me.
This is the code.

option 1

```
Dim availability As New List(Of String)
        If dtpavailability.Value = Date.Today Then availability.Add("Can start to work anytime") Else availability.Add("Can start to work by " + dtpavailability.Value.Date)
```

Option 2

```
Dim availability As New List(Of String)
        If dtpavailability.Value = Today Then availability.Add("Can start to work anytime") Else availability.Add("Can start to work by " + dtpavailability.Value.Date)
```

Option 3

```
Dim availability As New List(Of String)
        If dtpavailability.Value = TimeOfDay Then availability.Add("Can start to work anytime") Else availability.Add("Can start to work by " + dtpavailability.Value.Date)
```

Output

```
Textbox1.text = String.Join(vbNewLine, availability)
```

I tried these options but I still can't achieve what I want for my practice project.
I want the textbox1 to show the "Can start to work anytime" if I don't change the date on the date time picker which has the date today on my computer system.

Please help me correct my code.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that your `DateTimePicker` does actually contain `Date.Today`. I would wager that what's happening is that you have configured it to show just the date but you have ignored the fact that the actual value has a time portion too. I'd also wager that you haven't actually used the debugger and put a breakpoint on that `If` statement to see for yourself what the value is. You're a developer, not a user, so you need to use the development tools, not just look at the UI. If you don't know how to debug, you should stop what you're doing and learn now. It's an essential skill.

Comment: Yes. I'm still in the stage of learning. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTimePicker` includes the Time in the `Value` Property.

To get only the date, you'll need:

`dtpavailability.Value.Date`

Comment: This answer is correct. I can move on now to my next experiment.

Comment: Thank you.

This is what I've done using your answer.
    `Dim availability As New List(Of String)
        If dtpavailability.Value.Date = Today Then availability.Add("Can start to work anytime") Else availability.Add("Can start to work by " + dtpavailability.Value.Date)

        TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, availability)`